# Make a reference between two schemes with sequelize creates an error

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I try to make a reference between two database schemes. The first scheme is `clinicdatabase`  and the second is `supportdatabase`

this is the model which is creating the error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Failed to open the referenced table 'supportdatabase.clinics'
```

My model `Staff` (scheme: `clinicdatabase`), which needs the id, as a foreign key, from the model `Clinic` (scheme: `supportdatabase`) looks like:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        const Staff = sequelize.define("Staff", {

            STAFF_PASSWORD: DataTypes.STRING,
            CLI_CLINICID: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: {
                        tableName: "clinics",
                        schema: "clinicdatabase"
                    },
                    key: 'id'
                }
            }
        },
        );  
        return Staff;
    }
```

Both schemes are connected and they are working. Is these reference even possible? Do i need some permissions for the schemes? If yes do you know wher to add this or what the right syntax is?

Comment: you can use association instead of this .

Comment: i tried associations already, but there is also this errror if i assocaiate a table from an other schema

Comment: if you have already defined association than you don't need to define references.  if you still not get it please paste your association code .